# Find standard deviation from file C++

Tags: c++, standard-deviation

I have coding to find standard deviation from the file provided. My lecturer suggests doing it in function. This is the coding that I have tried. But there are errors in calling function in main function. It says std cannot be covert to float. What should I do to find the standard deviation in the file?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

float calculateSD(float namefile);

int main()
{
   string input;  
   ifstream namefile("payment.txt"); 

   if (!namefile)
       return (cout << " ERROR : cannot open file.\n"), 1; 

   while (getline(namefile, input)) 
        cout << input << endl;

   namefile.clear();   
   namefile.seekg(0);  

   int a {}, b {}, c {};
   nameFile >> a >> b >> c ;

   calculateSD(nameFile >> a >> b >> c);
}

float calculateSD(float nameFile)
{
   float sum1 = 0.0, sum2 = 0.0, sum3 = 0.0;
   float mean1, mean2, mean3;
   float standardDeviation1 = 0.0, standardDeviation2 = 0.0, standardDeviation3 = 0.0;

    for (int a {}, b {}, c {}; namefile >> a >> b >> c; )
  {
    sum1 += a;
    sum2 += b;
    sum3 += c;
  }

    mean1 = sum1/10;
    mean2 = sum2/10;
    mean3 = sum3/10;

   for (int a {}, b {}, c {}; nameFile >> a >> b >> c ; )
  {
        standardDeviation1 += pow(a - mean1, 2);
        standardDeviation2 += pow(b - mean2, 2);
        standardDeviation3 += pow(c - mean3, 2);
  }

 cout << "Standard Deviation 1  = " << sqrt(standardDeviation1 / 10) << endl;
 cout << "Standard Deviation 2 = " << sqrt(standardDeviation2 / 10)<< endl;
 cout << "Standard Deviation 3 = " << sqrt(standardDeviation3 / 10)<< endl;

return 0;
}
```

Really appreciate if you guys could help me

Comment: please do not paraphrase the errors, but include the compiler error message in the question

Comment: `float nameFile` this looks very weird.

Comment: `float calculateSD(std::iostream&);`?

Answer (score 0):

You have quite a lot wrong going on. First off your function

```
float calculateSD(float nameFile);
```

for some reason accepts `float nameFile`, but you probably meant `ifstream& nameFile` (though the way you named this variable is confusing still).

After that in `main()` you try to call this function like this

```
int a {}, b {}, c {};
nameFile >> a >> b >> c ;

calculateSD(nameFile >> a >> b >> c);
```

Why would you read 6 numbers from your file before you started calculating standard deviation? Now your results might be incorrect. Not to mention that you have a typo - you define your stream as `ifstream namefile("payment.txt");`, note that it's called `namefile`, without capital `F`, but later you try to use it as `nameFile` variable, which doesn't exist. You probably meant to pass it like this:

```
int main()
{
   string input;  
   ifstream namefile("payment.txt"); 

   if (!namefile)
       return (cout << " ERROR : cannot open file.\n"), 1; 

   while (getline(namefile, input)) 
        cout << input << endl;

   namefile.clear();   
   namefile.seekg(0);  
   calculateSD(namefile);
}
```

Comment: Alexey, can i know what should be my function prototype ?  because at calculateSD(namefile) still error cannot convert to float

Comment: `float calculateSD(ifstream& nameFile);` as I already said, and as you were told in the comments

Comment: alright, I run the coding and there is no more error. However, I get 0 for all standard deviation

Comment: This is because you try to read file all over again, but you didn't reset the position of your stream to 0, so the loop that changes `standardDeviation1` does **no** iterations (`nameFile` produces no more values)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying split to function this is good. Problem is that you have problem grasping what should be passed to a function.

Try this way:

```cpp
std::vector<double> loadValues(std::istream& f) {
     double x;
     std::vector<double> v;
     while(f >> x) v.push_back(x);
     return v;
}

double standardDeviationFrom(const std::vector<double>& v)
{
     ... // do it yourself
}

double standardDeviationFrom(std::istream& f)
{
    return standardDeviationFrom(loadValues(f))
}

double standardDeviationFrom(std::filesystem::path p)
{
    std::ifstream f{p};
    if (!f) {
        std::perror("standardDeviationFrom");
        return std::nan("1");
    }
    return standardDeviationFrom(f);
}
```